# boost/smart_ptr build error

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, g++

I meet some error when I try to build my code which is very old and include
"<boost/smart_ptr.hpp>".

```
    In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_array.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr.hpp:22,
                 from ../para/SSParameters.h:19,
                 from SSShmooTestAnalyzer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:83:66: error: 'a' has not been declared
     template<class Y, class D, class A> shared_array( Y * p, D d, A a ): px( p ), pn( p, d, a )
                                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_array.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr.hpp:22,
                 from ../para/SSParameters.h:19,
                 from SSShmooTestAnalyzer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:182:64: error: 'a' has not been declared
     template<class Y, class D, class A> void reset( Y * p, D d, A a )
                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_array.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr.hpp:22,
                 from ../para/SSParameters.h:19,
                 from SSShmooTestAnalyzer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp: In constructor 'boost::shared_array<T>::shared_array(Y*, D, int)':
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:83:90: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope

         template<class Y, class D, class A> shared_array( Y * p, D d, A a ): px( p ), pn( p, d, a )
                                                                                              ^
    In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_array.hpp:17:0,
                     from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr.hpp:22,
                     from ../para/SSParameters.h:19,
                     from SSShmooTestAnalyzer.cpp:10:
    /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp: In member function 'void boost::shared_array<T>::reset(Y*, D, int)':
    /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:184:26: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
             this_type( p, d, a ).swap( *this );
                              ^
```

And there is also some errors in allocate_shared_array.hpp

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/make_shared.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr.hpp:28,
                 from SSEMAP.h:14,
                 from SSDomainResult.h:20,
                 from SSResultAnalyzerFactory.h:14,
                 from SSResultAnalyzerFactory.cpp:8:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp: In function 'typename boost::detail::sp_if_array<T>::type boost::allocate_shared_noinit(const int&, std::size_t)':
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp:220:52: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         boost::detail::allocate_array_helper<A, T2[]> a1(allocator, n1, &p2);
                                                    ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp:220:56: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
         boost::detail::allocate_array_helper<A, T2[]> a1(allocator, n1, &p2);
                                                        ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp:220:75: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
         boost::detail::allocate_array_helper<A, T2[]> a1(allocator, n1, &p2);
                                                                           ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp: In function 'typename boost::detail::sp_if_size_array<T>::type boost::allocate_shared_noinit(const int&)':
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp:239:53: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         boost::detail::allocate_array_helper<A, T2[N]> a1(allocator, &p2);
                                                     ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp:239:57: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
         boost::detail::allocate_array_helper<A, T2[N]> a1(allocator, &p2);
                                                         ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/allocate_shared_array.hpp:239:72: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
         boost::detail::allocate_array_helper<A, T2[N]> a1(allocator, &p2);
                                                                        ^
```

I cannot understand why it will post the error.

It can be built successful in red hat 5 , and boost 1.33.1 , gcc 4.1.2 .

But it cannot be built in red hat 7 , and boost 1.53.0 , gcc 4.8.2 .

I know the environment is very different from the old. But I also want to try to build it successful. It is better to build without code changed.

---

SSShmooTestAnalyzer.cpp has no code about boost and smart_ptr. It is just include the header called SSParameters.h.

I am sorry that I cannot show you all the code about my project. I can just show you some code about boost and smart_ptr. Should I show something more ?

SSParameters.h:

```
#include "tml_base.h"
#include "SSPara.h"
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


namespace sols
{
  class ITestSetControl;
}

using sols::ITestSetControl;
using std::vector;

namespace source_sync
{
  class CSSParameters
  {
  public:

............

    boost::shared_ptr<CSSEdgePara> &getEdgePara()
    {
      return mpEdgePara;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<CSSTimingPara> &getTimingPara()
    {
      return mpTimingPara;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<CSSResultPara> &getResultPara()
    {
      return mpResultPara;
    }

    const boost::shared_ptr<CSSResultPara> &getResultPara() const
    {
      return mpResultPara;
    }

    const boost::shared_ptr<ITestSetControl> &getTestSetControl() const
    {
      return mpTestSet;
    }

..........

 private:

.........

    boost::shared_ptr<CSSResultPara> mpResultPara;
    boost::shared_ptr<CSSEdgePara> mpEdgePara;
    boost::shared_ptr<CSSTimingPara> mpTimingPara;
    boost::shared_ptr<ITestSetControl> mpTestSet;

.......

 };
}
```

Comment: Ultimately the error is unlikely to be in Boost. Instead it's a much bigger chance it's in your code, the code which you are not showing us.

Comment: I see, but which code should I show you? These errors are generated by headers, so I don't know which code I should show you.

Comment: Well if you look at the error messages one of the errors is originating in `SSShmooTestAnalyzer.cpp` and another in `SSResultAnalyzerFactory.cpp`. It might be a good idea to look through those files, or *your* header listed in the messages. Try to refactor out the use of any of the smart pointers one by one and see when the errors go away.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  I cannot show you all the code. Because It is too much. And the errors are all generated by headers , just like "SSResultAnalyzerFactory.cpp : 8 " is the code " #include <SSResultAnalyzerFactory.h>" , the same as "SSResultAnalyzerFactory.h : 14". So I cannot chose which code I should show you. Could you please help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: I guessed it was to much code to show, which is why I gave the advice of refactor the code until the error goes away. Then you have narrowed it down and can hopefully create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thank you very much for your advice. But I cannot refactor it because I cannot even understand what is it. The code are programmed by someone who I cannot contact only when I can make sure he must refactor the code for my job.

Comment: Just a small and unrelated note: Passing or returning a shared pointer *by reference* kind of negates the whole reason of having a shared pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like you missed a closing brace/parenthesis/semicolon in one of your header files which is included before boost header files.